# Java exception pattern

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code for exception.
If the input does not match with the pattern below (this is just example) it will throw an exception message.

```
8454T3477-90
```

This is the code that I came up with. However, I'm not sure if this is the right patter...

```
public void setLegalDescription(String legalDescription) throws MyInvalidLegalDescriptionException
    {
        String valid = ("[0-9999][A-Z][0-9999]-[0-99]");
        if (!legalDescription.matches(valid))
        {
            //throw new MyInvalidLegalDescriptionException("Invalid format! Should be " + "e.g 4050F8335-14");
        }
        this.legalDescription = legalDescription;
    }
```

Comment: use an online tester/debugger for regex to verify https://regex101.com/ Tim's answer is correct...

Answer (score 6):

Your pattern is slightly off.  Try this version:

```
String valid = ("[0-9]{4}[A-Z][0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}");
if (!legalDescription.matches(valid))
{
    // throw new MyInvalidLegalDescriptionException("Invalid format! Should be " + "e.g 4050F8335-14");
}
```

An explanation of the regex:

```
[0-9]{4}   any 4 digits
[A-Z]      any capital letter
[0-9]{4}   any 4 digits
-          a dash
[0-9]{2}   any 2 digits
```

It should be noted that `[0-9999]` does *not* match any number between 0 and 9999.  Rather, it actually just matches a single digit between 0 and 9.

If the width of your identifier is not fixed, then perhaps use this pattern:

```
[0-9]{1,4}[A-Z][0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,2}
```

Comment: If the goal is to match any number between 0 and 9999, I think you want `{1,4}` as a quantifier?

Comment: @JornVernee I guess that would depend on whether zero would be fixed width (`0000`), or not (just `0`).  I am assuming fixed width.

Comment: correct also in the explanation [0-9]{4} to [0-9]{2}